# Need item selected from drop down to compare a quantity of that item and update table

Tags: vba, ms-access, compare, product-quantity

So I've been building an MS Access database for our business to track repair tickets and other info.  I'm almost finished with it, but want to add a function based on a selection of a drop down.

I have a table with items listed that we use for repairs, along with an on-hand quantity.  Within the repair ticket form, I want to be able to select an item from a drop down, compare the on-hand quantity of that item within the table, which will then determine the next steps.  Essentially, if there is an on-hand > 0, then the status of the ticket changes, as well as update the quantity of of the table (like if on-hand = 25, selecting that item automatically removes 1 from the quantity, making it 24, etc.).  In addition, if the repair isn't approved, it should obviously add 1 to the quantity since that item wasn't used for that repair.

There is already a drop down that populates the item to the repairticket table, and want to use the same drop down for the added function, if that makes any sense.

I can write the code for status changes and whatnot, but don't know how to make it compare the quantities and update the separate Item List table.

Any help and guidance would be much appreciated!! And thanks in advance!!

-Andrew

Comment: There is one school of thought that inventory balances should not be saved to table but calculated from transaction records. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html. Can pull data from table using DLookup() or DSum() domain aggregate function. Can use UPDATE action sql to modify data in table.

Comment: The first option is an interesting idea, however I wonder if that would make things more complicated down the road.  We usually take inventory at least 3 times per year (small company, so pretty easy to do), so updating the counts would be imperative anyhow.  And I completely forgot about DLookup()... Thank you!!!